# Dishonored stopped working?

Tags: technical-issues, pc, dishonored

I have just bought Dishonored yesterday and it worked fine, but now sometimes when I open a door that goes to a different area a box pops up and says Dishonored has stopped working. The game then closes and when I start it up again it erases my last autosave. There is no place where it has happened every time but frequently it is when I've been detected and running from guards.

The text of the error message says:

> Dishonored stopped working
>   Search for a solution online
>   Close program
>   Debug program

Comment: What's the text in the box? Does this always occur at the same location? You need to provide more information for this question to be answerable.

Comment: In line with @Vaishali's comment have you tried lowering your graphics settings completey and playing the same part that crashes your game again to see if it works?

Comment: Might sound really dumb but did you try reinstalling the game? Sounds like a section of a code didn't get downloaded.

Answer (score -2):

Use the Program Compatibility Troubleshooter on the game, and/or fiddle with compatibility settings until it works.